# I can't print the vprintf log by journalctl

Tags: yocto, journal

I using yocto 2.0.2 my apps are running by systemd.
So, I can check log by journalctl -u app name.

But, one of my app is not printing a log by journalctl.

I using the vprintf function and it is OK to run binary file.
Like "/usr/bin/app". This case printing a log on console.

But running by systemd, log is not printing by journalctl.
Other apps are printing a log.

Is anyone know this reason??

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with `fflush(stdout)`.